# I want to display modal dialog on page load and also with a button toggle, both

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The thing is that i need to display both, modal dialog when page load and also with a button toggle. Now the button toggle is working fine, I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 in wordpress site built with my own template. But i can't reach display the modal dialog on page load. I have enqueue bootstrap.min.js with a jquery dependencies, for the rest functions os my site all working like expective. This is the code that I'm using for.

```js
var jqmodalshow = jQuery.noConflict();
jqmodalshow(document).ready(function(){
        jqmodalshow("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">BUTTON</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the HTML you wrote to create the modal was malformed. You had repeated the same `id` in two locations which is invalid, and you'd nested copies of `.modal` and `.modal-dialog`. The JS is valid and working.

If you fix the HTML issues then the code works fine.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">BUTTON</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for respond and Sorry for duplicate id elements that was carelessness, but still not working, console message say Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1379)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2) i was checking if there is a duplicate jQuery, bt look like everthing is fine with that.

Comment: That error means you haven't included bootstrap in the page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the id `myModal` that probably gives you an error. You have to give them different ids:

```
<div id="myModalDialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
…
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
…
```

and then the JS:

```
var jqmodalshow = jQuery.noConflict();
jqmodalshow(document).ready(function(){
        jqmodalshow("#myModalDialog").modal('show');
        jqmodalshow("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: I was checking both answer in different sites, and both working fine, right now i don't know what is causing the problem on my site...

Comment: I think the other already told you, that probably bootstrap.js not is implemented correctly.

Comment: That's correct. I had two jquery version, in the same project, I deleted the old one version, I left the newest, but when I put enqueue bootstrap file I changed the name of the handle parameter in the function, wp_enqueue_script('jquery_newest'... rest of the parameters); I deleted _newest leaving just jquery. After that works perfectly. This wordpress page also help me a lot https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-and-js-libraries-included-and-registered-by-wordpress